# SQLPLUS does not run using oracle instant client on win XP SP3

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, oracle-call-interface

I have a computer which acts as a server for Oracle database 11g Enterprise.  I want to use another computer, a PC that is running Windows XP SP3, as a client of this server.

So I decided to install Oracle Instant Client 11.2.0.4.0 on client PC. I downloaded zipped file from Oracle OTN  and extract it into folder like `c:\oracle\instantclient11.2.0.4.0`. Then I added this path to the system path variable, and created another system variable called `TNS_ADMIN` for variable name with the same path for Oracle Instant Client, `c:\oracle\instantclient11.2.0.4.0` .

Finally I copied the tnsnames.ora from server pc.

So I want to try to run the sqlplus from cmd.exe but the error is :

```
The procedure entry point OCIBindByName2 could not be located in the dynamic link library OCI.dll .
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: It may be that you have a version of the Oracle client software that was installed as part of some other package. Try this: open a Command Line window, C:, CD \, DIR /S OCI.DLL and see how many versions of this DLL appear. Good luck.

Comment: yes i searched in my computer for all files named OCI.DLL , and yes i found another program have OCI.DLL as part of it , so how to deal with this conflict

Comment: Well, you could rename the "other" version of OCI.DLL to something else (for example, OCI_OTHER.DLL) to see if this fixes the problem. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Have you set ORACLE_HOME to c:\oracle\instantclient11.2.0.4.0 too?

It should be fixed in 11.2 though as descibed in 343666.1 :

> This dependence on ORACLE_HOME issue has been resolved in Bug: 5532439
>   OCI.DLL MUST APPROPRIATELY CALL SETDLLDIRECTORY.   The fix is to call
>   SetDllDirectory based on the location of where the OCI.DLL is located.
>   Workaround for this issue:
>
> 1. Do an Instant Client Installation, for example into, C:\Oracle\EZClient102
> 2. Set the ORACLE_HOME environment variable to the ORACLE_HOME of the Instant Client.
>
> set ORACLE_HOME=C:\Oracle\EZClient102
>
> Then the Instant Client DLL's should be loaded from
>   C:\Oracle\EZClient102\bin